# To remove xml tag using freemarker function

Tags: freemarker

I am manipulating data in free marker and I got result through third party web service in below given format:

```
<TEXTFORMAT INDENT="3" LEADING="5"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="11" LETTERSPACING="0">welcome to first program</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
<TEXTFORMAT INDENT="3" LEADING="5"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="11" KERNING="0">Example </FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
<TEXTFORMAT INDENT="3" LEADING="5"><LI><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="11" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0">Suggest test</FONT></LI></TEXTFORMAT>
```

So I want to remove tag in above code and want to fetch plain text data. Is there any free-marker or syntax for the same task?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in for converting HTML to plain text. It's not something related to the duties of FreeMarker really. There are some Java libraries that were specifically made to deal with HTML, and may have functions to convert to plain text.

Comment: :- Can please specify name or any references to java libraries